# Which Version is useful AndEngine gles1 or gles2 for beginners in Game Field?

Tags: android, game-engine

I m new in Game Development Filed. I found that AndEngine is good for beginner so that i chose that but in which there are 2 versions gles1 and gles2 i tries both sample code and found that gles2 code is not run on enulator, it required actual device..!And in gles2 there are also BaseGameActivity and SimpleBaseGameActivity.So, i'm little bit confused that which is best.? Please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GLES1 is no longer going to be actively supported. Its not a matter of what's easier for beginners, its just that GLES2 supports new versions of OPENGL. Go GLES2 for sure, no doubt about it. Good luck!